# I need a way to create a handling fee that is a percentage of an an item

Tags: magento-connect

I have a client that needs a a handling fee of 14% of every item that a person purchases.  I have exhausted any further options to figure this out via magento connect.  Anyone have any Ideas?

Comment: Which shipping options are you using?

Comment: As far as I know the client handles their own shipping and use 14% of the products price for thier handling fee.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Magento Add Fee or Discount to Order Totals](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/)

```
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)f  
   ....
   $exist_amount = $quote->getFeeAmount();

   $total = $exist_amount * 1.14;
   $address->setFeeAmount($total);
   $address->setBaseFeeAmount($total);

   $quote->setFeeAmount($total);

  $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() + $address->getFeeAmount());
  $address->setBaseGrandTotal($address->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseFeeAmount());
  .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want different products to have this fee so...

Create a product attribute like 'handling' or something similar.  When you add products to the cart check each product to conditionally add this fee to the total!

Comment: I should add that its 14% of the price of the item.  Not sure if thats something that is doable in the attributes.  And I do not want to have to go back into every product and add the fee by hand.

Comment: Do you have a list of products (skus, whatever) that this will apply to?

Comment: Yes, but it applies to ALL products.

Comment: if it applies to all products that is the same as applying it to the total.  check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511309/add-custom-calculation-to-cart-total-and-grand-total-in-magento)

Comment: where do I save the class files

Comment: using ikantam method I am having trouble with the config.xml file when i paste it into the main default confix.xml it breaks the shopping cart

Comment: this module should help https://www.scommerce-mage.co.uk/magento-surcharge-or-additional-fee.html